# OS X Parallels: what are ways to speed up Windows 10 Pro virtualization?

Tags: windows, performance, virtualization, parallels-desktop

We have two OS X laptops running Windows 10 Pro in Parallels where the other laptop is terribly slow, despite allocating 4 "cores" and 8 GB to the virtual machine. Each laptop has 8 "cores" (with Hyper Threading) and 16 GB. We don't know yet why the other laptop is so slow.

**What are ways to speed up Windows 10 Pro virtualisation in OS X's Parallels?**

Comment: "Terribly slow" in comparison to what?  Are they *identical* laptops in both hardware and software?  It's a bit vague on the details.

Comment: @Allan yes they are identical, The slower is setup a little bit later than The faster.